# Error in statement: return item.name.contains('$scope.inputQuery') ;

Tags: angularjs

The html(jade) contains

```
body(ng-controller='myAppController')

    <input ng-model="inputQuery">

    ul
        li(ng-repeat="phone in phones|filter:query") {{phone.name}}
            p {{phone.snippet}}
```

the controller is defined as:

```
function myAppController($scope){


        $scope.query = function(item){
            return item.name.contains('$scope.inputQuery') ;

        }

$scope.phones = [ 

    {"name": "Nexus S",
 "snippet": "Fast just got faster with Nexus S."},
{"name": "Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."},
{"name": "MOTOROLA XOOM™",
 "snippet": "The Next, Next Generation tablet."}

];
}
```

The output is supposed to be, the 'phone' whose 'name' contains the 'input' letters. However there is no output. (no change depending upon input either)

Upon inspection, the following works:

```
$scope.query = function(item){
        return item.name; // or return item

    }
```

but even `return item.name.contains('N');` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `indexOf()` to check whether a string is a substring

```
$scope.query = function (item) {
    if ($scope.inputQuery === undefined || $scope.inputQuery === "" ) return item;
    return item.name.indexOf($scope.inputQuery) >= 0;
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKjWu/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.query = function (item) {
    return item.name.indexOf($scope.inputQuery || "") >= 0;
}
```

Modified @sza 's answer to add $scope to inputQuery. Should have used comment but I'm unable to comment yet. `|| ""` in case you want the list displayed upon loading the page (before typing into the input box).

http://jsfiddle.net/s5Pd7/1/